# include random slope in binomial mixed model

Tags: lme4, mixed-models

I am using a binomial GLMM to examine the relationship between presence of individuals (# hours/day) at a site over time. Since presence is measured daily for several individuals, I've included a random intercept for individual ID.

e.g.,

```
presence <- cbind(hours, 24-hours)
glmer(presence ~ time + (1 | ID), family = binomial)
```

I'd like to also look at using ID as a random slope, but I don't know how to add this to my model.  I've tried the two different approaches below, but I'm not sure which is correct.

```
glmer(presence ~ time + (1 + ID), family = binomial)
Error: No random effects terms specified in formula

glmer(presence ~ time + (1 + ID | ID), family = binomial)
Error: number of observations (=1639) < number of random effects (=5476) for term (1 + ID | ID); the random-effects parameters are probably unidentifiable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a random slope for `ID` and have `ID` as a (level-two) grouping variable (see this documentation for more detail: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf).

The grouping variable, which is `ID` in the models below, is used as a variable for which to specify random effects. `model_1` gives random intercepts for the `ID` variable. `model_2` gives both random intercepts and random slopes for the `time` variable. In other words, `model_1` allows the intercept of the relationship between `presence` and `time` to vary with `ID`(the slope remains the same), whereas `model_2` allows for the both the intercept and slopes to vary with `ID`, so that the relationship between `presence` and `time` (i.e., the slope) can be different for each individual (`ID`).

`model_1 = glmer(presence ~ time + (1 | ID), family = binomial)`

`model_2 = glmer(presence ~ time + (1 + time | ID), family = binomial)`

I would also recommend:

Snijders, T. A. B., & Bosker, R. J. (2012). Multilevel analysis: an introduction to basic and advanced multilevel modeling (2nd ed.): Sage.

Comment: Thanks @arranjdavis for that very clear and helpful explanation, and the recommended literature.

Comment: You are welcome - happy to help, and thank you for accepting my answer. One other thing I thought of to go with the Snijders & Bosker (2012) reference above: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~snijders/ (that is the website that accompanies the book; it has some useful R code and data sets).